# How to set an attribute of type Collection<> to null in a resultMap?

Tags: mybatis

I have a result map that looks like this:

```
<resultMap id="myMap" type="myEntity">
    <id property="id" column="ID" />
    <result property="name" column="NAME" />
    <collection property="places" ofType="MyPlace" >
        <result property="placeName" column="PLACE_NAME" />
    </collection>
<resultMap>


<select id="mySelectStatement" parameterType="MyQuery" resultMap="myMap">
     ....
</select>
```

In the incoming parameter (MyQuery) of the select statement I have a flag that indicates whether the places should by joined and resolved or left out. Using the `<if test="myFlag" />`
construct this all works well.

Now, the only problem that I have is the following: When the flag indicates that the places should be resolved but there are no places connected with the entity then the resulting collection is empty (so far so good). However, when the flag indicates that the places should not be resolved, the resulting collection is also empty.

It is no longer decidable whether the field "places" is empty because there are simply no places or because they weren't being resolved at all. What I would like to have is some mechanism that sets the field "places" to ´null´ instead of returning an empty collection in the case that the flag that decides whether the places should be resolved is set to false.

EDIT:
Some more code to better understand the example

```
// MyEntity.java
public class MyEntity {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<MyPlace> places;
}

// MyQuery.java
public class MyQuery {
    private boolean myFlag;
    // getter & setter
}

// MyComponent.java
public class MyComponent {
    private MyMapper myMapper;

    public void findByQuery(MyQuery myQuery) {
        List<MyEntity> myEntities = myMapper.mySelectStatement();
        MyEntity firstEntity = myEntities.get(0);
        List<Place> places = firstEntity.getPlaces();
        if(places.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Hm I wonder why they are empty");    
        }
    }

}


// MyMapper.java
public interface MyMapper {
    List<MyEntity> mySelectStatement(MyQuery myQuery);
}

// MyMapper.xml

// result map from above

<select id="mySelectStatement" parameterType="MyQuery" resultMap="myMap">
     SELECT * FROM MY_ENTITY
     <if test="myFlag">
          LEFT OUTER JOIN PLACES ON .....
     </if> 
</select>
```

And some clarification: This all works in principle. The only problem that I have is that I can not distinguish between an empty collection "places" that is empty because there were no entries in the table AND an empty collection places that is empty because they were not supposed to be resolved in the first place.

My current solution is to check in MyComponent after the method call whether the query that was passed in has the flag set to false. If that is the case, the "places" variable is manually set to null.

Comment: I would suggest you have another property in your Java layer to record whether the places should be resolved or not.

Comment: Well this property is in the query object. But I don't want it in the result object. There I have a field, places, that should be null if it was not requested to be resolved or non null if it was requested to be resolved.

Comment: Please give a clearer example of how you manage to use <if test="myFlag" /> so we can see what we can do for your case

Comment: Added some more code

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have an object that has a Set of strings. It keeps returning an empty Set instead of making it null. I'd prefer it to be null because then my API will just not return it. Now it's returning it as empty.

Comment: Nope....I had to handle it on the Java side :(